# Plesk (WebPro): no SSL option available

Tags: https, security-certificate, plesk

I'm using Plesk 12 and defined a couple of websites that will be hosted on the server. However, continuing setup a few days later I had to find that only 1 of these websites allows me to configure SSL/add a CRT certificate, the others don't even display the option "SSL Certificates" in the "Website & Domains" site list, and in the "Hosting Options" of the respective sites, the SSL option is disabled.

How can I activate the SSL option for the other sites, too?

Comment: Are the other sites using a [shared IP address](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=68308.htm)? Are you [sharing](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/60324.htm) the SSL certificate?

Comment: yes, all are using the same IP, and 3 of those sites are in a shared certificate (Letsencrypt).

Comment: If they're using a shared IP, then you'll need to use a [SANS UCC](https://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm) certificate on that shared IP and use that as the shared SSL certificate (see the second link in my comment above). If you're using standard SSL's, you'll need to add dedicated IP addresses for each account.